# Pyinstaller gerando erro ao compilar varios scripts

Tags: pyinstaller

Ola boa noite estou compilando o python 3.6 estou usando o compilador pyinstaller para um script funciona perfeitamente. O problema é quando tenho que gerar vários  scripts que devem ser usados para que  o programa funcione exemplo (Menu.py, vendaDao.py, venda.py) quando gero o exe do menu.py ele não abre. Estou a um bom tempo empacado nisso. Se alguém souber, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite galera, estava rodando pela pagina e encontrei um amigo com o mesmo erro, e quando coloquei a imagem dentro da pasta dist, problema solucionado. 
Obrigado a todos por compartilhar problemas e soluções.